# how to show the combinaton too in this code?

Tags: python, recursion

This is my code to exchange a bank note to smaller coines and notes.it shows the number of combination but not the combination themselves.
how should I modify the code?

```
def exchange(a,coins):
    if a==0:
        return 1
    elif a<0 or len(coins)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return exchange(a,coins[1:])+exchange(a-coins[0],coins)
```

for example if coins=[1,5,10,50,100] and I want to exchange 100 the answer of my code is totall number of solutions. But I need to see the solution in a list of list like
[[100--1],[2--50],[1--50,4--10,10--1],etc]

Comment: Please update your question with an example of how you would call this function and the expected final return value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @quamrana I add an example to the question

Comment: I don't understand your example list. What does the `--` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the base cases of your recursive function only return numbers. If you want your result to be a list of combinations, you need to at least return lists from your base cases.

Comment: Not incorrect, but elaboration and perhaps an example would improve the quality of this answer.